# How can I force a rnorm simulation to give me positive numbers only?

Tags: r, simulation

I am running a simulation where i want values to start at zero.
The histogram shows a distribution with negative values though I tried specifying that I want positive values.

Comment: `abs(rnorm(1))` positive number guaranteed.

Comment: "How can I force a rnorm simulation to give me positive numbers only?" -- you can't. If you remove negative numbers from the support of the distribution then you are no longer talking about normal variables. If you are using normal variables to model positive quantities, and the mean and variance are such that negative values occur with a non-negligible probability, you probably need to rethink your model.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem with negative values!

Comment: Note that `abs(rnorm(10, 29000, 10000))` has a distribution whose mean is larger than 29000 and whose standard deviation is smaller than 100000. Using `abs()` could skew the results of the simulation.

Comment: @JohnColeman I read that rgamma is appropriate for such cases but I didn't understand how the gamma function works so thought rnorm will be an ok alternative

Comment: You should consult a statistician.

Comment: Agreeing with JohnColeman and Roland, calling it "positive normal" is misleading since *Normal* is "asymptotically infinite" in both directions. If you have constraints, you might consider a [*Truncated Normal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution), supported in R via the [`truncnorm`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=truncnorm) package ([source repo](https://github.com/olafmersmann/truncnorm)).

Comment: are you looking for a `?Lognormal` distribution instead? `rlnorm(10)`

Comment: @chinsoon12 I ended up using lognormal . Thank you

Comment: Incidentally, the following web application for experimental data simulation may be useful in the present context: https://github.com/pablobernabeu/Experimental-data-simulation